# Making opaque layer in OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS.

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, blending

I'm working on a simple 3D application with OpenGL ES 2 on iOS.

I just followed steps in "OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS" in Apple Developer Site.

I wanted make the OpenGL View entirely opaque for better performance as suggested in the document. So, I did as below.

```
CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;        
eaglLayer.opaque = TRUE;
```

And, I ran the application with the Core Animation instrument. Then, I turned on 'Color Blended Layers' in Debug Options in Core Animation instrument.

Then, the entire screen became reddish which means the entire view was being blended. I tested another example OpenGL apps from Apple, but they were all greenish with the instrument.

The document dosen't say anything about this except making the layer opaque just like I did.
What else could there be possible cause for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set the alpha component to 1.0 when you call glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0).